Numpy neural network not learning (stuck on 10% accuracy) - Python
So I am trying to build a basic ANN using numpy. The thing is I keep getting an accuracy prediction of around 10% and I don't understand why that is. Here is all the code.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

data = np.array(data)
m, n = data.shape
np.random.shuffle(data)

data_train = data.T
X_train = data_train[1:n]
Y_train = data_train[0]

def init_params():
    W1 = np.random.randn(10, 784)
    b1 = np.random.rand(10, 1)
    W2 = np.random.randn(10, 10)
    b2 = np.random.randn(10, 1)
    return W1, b1, W2, b2

def ReLU(Z):
    return np.maximum(0, Z)

def softmax(Z):
        e = np.exp(Z - Z.max(axis=0, keepdims=True))
        return e/e.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)

def forward_prop(W1, b1, W2, b2, X):
    Z1 = W1.dot(X) + b1
    A1 = ReLU(Z1)
    Z2 = W2.dot(A1) + b2
    A2 = softmax(Z2)
    return Z1, A1, Z2, A2

def one_hot(Y):
    one_hot_Y = np.zeros((Y.size, Y.max() + 1))
    one_hot_Y[np.arange(Y.size), Y] = 1
    one_hot_Y = one_hot_Y.T
    return one_hot_Y

def deriv_ReLU(Z):
    return (Z > 0).astype(int)


def back_prop(Z1, A1, Z2, A2, W2, X, Y):
    m = Y.size
    one_hot_Y = one_hot(Y)
    dZ2 = A2 - one_hot_Y
    dW2 = 1 / m * dZ2.dot(A1.T)
    db2 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ2, 1).reshape(-1, 1)
    dZ1 = W2.T.dot(dZ2) * deriv_ReLU(Z1)
    dW1 = 1 / m * dZ1.dot(X.T)
    db1 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ1, 1).reshape(-1, 1)
    return dW1, db1, dW2, db2

def update_params(W1, b1, W2, b2, dW1, db1, dW2, db2, alpha):
    W1 = W1 - alpha * dW1
    db1 = b1 - alpha * db1
    W2 = W2 - alpha * dW2
    db2 = b2 - alpha * db2
    return W1, b1, W2, b2

def get_predictions(A2):
    return np.argmax(A2, 0)

def get_accuracy(predictions, Y):
    print(predictions, Y)
    return np.sum(predictions == Y) / Y.size

def gradient_descent(X, Y, iterations, alpha):
    W1, b1, W2, b2 = init_params()
    for i in range(iterations):
        Z1, A1, Z2, A2 = forward_prop(W1, b1, W2, b2, X)
        dW1, db1, dW2, db2 = back_prop(Z1, A1, Z2, A2, W2, X, Y)
        W1, b1, W2, b2 = update_params(W1, b1, W2, b2, dW1, db1, dW2, db2, alpha)
        if (i % 50):
            print(f'Iteration: {i}')
            print(f'Accuracy: {get_accuracy(get_predictions(A2), Y)}')
    return W1, b1, W2, b2

W1, b1, W2, b2 = gradient_descent(X_train, Y_train, 100, 0.1)

I thought that it may be an issue with the data I was using, but after trying new data it isn't. SO clearly somewhere in the back propagation (I'm guessing) I messed something up and switched some variables. The data being used is MNIST data set of handwritten numbers and there are 10 classes.
I did a little bit more digging and I noticed that actually the model seems to be outputting a single number as a prediction the whole time. I don't understand why.

what data? what task? (how many classes?)

I can't debug your backprop just by looking at it, but 1 comment first: numpy.sum() has a keepdims parameter which, if you set to True, keeps an empty dimension where you summed.
Might be useful to use that instead of all these reshape(-1, 1) operations.

In particular are there 10 classes?

Yes so the data being used is MNIST data set of handwritten numbers and there are 10 classes.

Okay so I managed to fix my own issues with the help of chatGPT:
I had a few typos in there, notably in the update_params() function where I updated the derivatives instead of updating the actual layers.
Bias Update Issue:
There's a potential issue in your update_params function for updating the biases:
db1 = b1 - alpha * db1

This line should be:
b1 = b1 - alpha * db1

Similarly, check db2 to ensure:
b2 = b2 - alpha * db2

Since the wrong variables are being updated, the biases remain unchanged during training, preventing effective learning.
What really changed the game though was these next two points:
Weight Initialization:
Ensure that your weight initialization does not produce too large or too small values. A standard approach is to scale weights by ​sqrt(1/n), where:
n is the number of inputs for a given layer.
W1 = np.random.randn(10, 784) * np.sqrt(1 / 784)
W2 = np.random.randn(10, 10) * np.sqrt(1 / 10)

This prevents issues with vanishing/exploding gradients.
This was a game changer along with this:
Data Normalization:
Make sure your input data X (pixels in this case) are normalized. Often, pixel values range from 0 to 255, so you should divide your input data by 255 to keep values between 0 and 1.
X_train = X_train / 255.0

This normalization often helps stabilize learning.
And there you have it. I am able to get 90% accuracy within 100 iterations. I'm going to now test different activation functions and find the most adequate. Thank you chatGPT.

Please see the StackOverflow policy on AI-generated content. It is ok -to me at least- to ask for AI help for debugging, but you really must avoid copy-pasting the AI-generated answer.

Ok, sorry i'm new to stack overflow
